# Mix Horizontal and Vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm currently thinking about creating a website for a school project. I want to stay in a OnePage style, but with a lot of interaction.

I thought of mixing vertical scrolling (obvious) but I also want to add some section using horizontal scrolling (e.g : show all the project in a section and navigate through them using horizontal scroll)

Do you have any clue to start my research ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: try [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/going_horizontal.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would use Fullpage.js: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/. A nice framework that enables you to build sites like [this](http://wise-recorder.cloudvent.net). Beware that it is not (completely) free.